# Correctly matching files with a specific word in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using the following syntax to match files with `*Log` in the file name and force log highlighting syntax (which is available [here](https://github.com/dzeban/vim-log-syntax)):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *Log setlocal syntax=log
```

I would like to expand this expression to capture all possible variations including *someNamelog, some_name_LoG, some_session_log_some_date, some_session_log121231* and so on. In practice, I would like to capture all instances of the word `log` irrespectively of case. Initially, I've tried using:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *(l|L)og setlocal syntax=log
```

to capture `log` and `Log` but this does not work. Is there any way to do it that would not require multiple `au BufRead,BufNewFile` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use globbing, like in your shell:

```
autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *{log,Log,lOg,loG,LOG}* setlocal syntax=log
```

(I'll leave the rest of the list up to you)

See `:help file-pattern`.